# Trying to install fonts on Linux Mint Lisa, but it looks like I have a permissions or ownership problem

Tags: permissions, linux-mint, software-installation, fonts, non-root-user

I downloaded the Source Code Pro family of fonts, but cannot install them via the Font Viewer.  If I give myself admin powers, I can manually add them to the rest of the fonts, so I'm guessing it's a permission issue.

What would I need to do to install them via the Font Viewer?

As a slight aside, I also read something about making sure the fonts were in the font cache as well.  Is that necessary?  If so, what's that entail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can copy the fonts in to `~/.fonts` folder and run `fc-cache -fv` command to cache them. To do this you don't need admin privileges.

Comment: `-f` shouldn't be needed (but won't hurt, unless you have a lot of fonts and/or very big ones, then it will take a while)